# Additions to menagerie were strange but appreciated

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

For astronomical information, engage the flux capacitor (May or June 2022) and then find them.

Then make Cupid drop stuff.

Then you “drop” stuff.

```
C A D L A A  
E D E N N D  
S H E N P I  
S H G O S I  
W O R U W T
```

[image: 6 x 6 grid with arrows (solid and dashed)]

---

Hint:

> What was the nephew and Captain Squared doing back then?

2nd hint:

> Both grids have 6 columns.

Revised 3rd hint:

> For some of the rules, say 5/6 of **“drop”** aloud.

4th hint:

> What was I doing back then?  And who the heck is Captain Squared?

5th hint:

> [Cupid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cupid) can keep his bow.

6th hint:

> “Horny” mythical creatures.

7th hint:

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dropquote

---

<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Monthly Topic Challenge #15: Multi Puzzle — two (or more) puzzles in one](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7514/monthly-topic-challenge-15-multi-puzzle-two-or-more-puzzles-in-one)</sub>

---

Comment: I have never seen a rot13(Qebcdhbgr) puzzle before. Very interesting!

Comment: @Alaiko Well give this one a try.  The 6th hint might help you solve this part of the puzzle.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*For astronomical information, engage the flux capacitor (May or June 2022) and then find them.*

> Engaging the *[flux capacitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DeLorean_time_machine#Flux_capacitor)* means we travel through time to May or June 2022. In those months OP posted [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/116401/three-of-my-find-the-stars-puzzles) and [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/116449/more-of-my-find-the-stars-puzzles-set-2) puzzle called "Find-the-stars" (*astronomical information*), a genre OP invented and whose rules are explained there. (This fits with the first and fourth hint. OP was making those puzzles then and the Captain Squared must be yours truly (caPNCApn) who solved both of those puzzles. A comment on one of those puzzles tells about a nephew enjoying them.)

So lets find them!

> First let's eliminate squares pointed to by dashed arrows.
>  [image]

> Now two of our stars are forced by solid arrows.
>  [image]

> We can eliminate the other squares on the same row or column as a star.
>  [image]

> Now the solid arrow pointing southwest forces a star and we can eliminate other squares in its row and column.
>  [image]

> Now the second row is forced. Then the third and finally the fourth.
>  [image]

*Then make Cupid drop stuff.*

> What could Cupid drop? Hint 5 says he can keep his bow. So we must be dropping arrows. (Since we were never instructed to X out squares, we can drop those too.)
>  [image]

*Then you “drop” stuff.*

> As hinted by OP, this refers to a [Dropquote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dropquote) puzzle. With some trial and error we can drop the letters into the grid like this:
>  [image]
>  and it reads "**WHEN I ADOPTED UNICORNS SHE WAS GLAD**", which is confirmed by the similar meaning of the title.